# Get remainder of a list

Tags: python, algorithm, loops

I have a python code that gets all the rows from a table and inserts it into another in blocks of 1000.

```
allRows = db.getAllRows() #12.345 elements
package = []
for idx, pr in enumerate(allRows):
    package.append(pr)
    if (idx + 1) % 1000 == 0:
        db.inserPackage(package)
        package = []
```

this code works and inserts the package of 1000 rows, but if the length of the list is, for example 12.345, I'm losing the rest of the list after 12.000 (345) elements.

How could I get the remain of the list and insert it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If don't mind using `itertools`, there is a convenient method to do that:

```
import itertools

allRows = db.getAllRows() # 12.345 elements
while True:
    package = list(itertools.islice(allRows, 1000))
    if not package: # no more elements
        break
    db.insertPackage(package)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just call `db.insertPackage(package)` at the end of your loop, if package is not empty:

```
allRows = db.getAllRows() #12.345 elements
package = []
for idx, pr in enumerate(allRows):
    package.append(pr)
    if (idx + 1) % 1000 == 0:
        db.inserPackage(package)
        package = []
if package:
    db.inserPackage(package)
```